# How invoke a PubSub function from the GCP Functions GUI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have the following function deployed:

```
interface MessageData {
  reviewId: string;
}

export const applyPreAssessRules = functions
  .pubsub.topic("applyPreAssessRules")
  .onPublish(async (message) => {
    const { reviewId } = message.json as MessageData;
    ...
  }
```

The cloud platform GUI provides a page to test the function, but I can't figure out how to format the input.

I've tried several things including:

```
{"reviewId": "LRuvmv14u7c47IRiravi"}
```

```
{"message": {"reviewId": "LRuvmv14u7c47IRiravi"}}
```

```
{"message": { "json": {"reviewId": "LRuvmv14u7c47IRiravi"}}}
```

I keep getting the following output:

> Error: function execution failed. Details:
>   The first argument must be one of type string, Buffer, ArrayBuffer, Array, or Array-like Object. Received type undefined

What am I missing?

I've deployed the function using Firebase. Don't know if that makes a difference...

Comment: Just for confirmation. The function is working as expected in Firebase but is not in GCP?

Comment: The function itself is running fine. I wonder how to pass a valid JSON payload into it from GCP, given that we have this test UI

Comment: There are some examples on how to use Cloud Functions with PubSub [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub).  As per the error you are getting, I think you should use `JSON.stringify(messageObject)` .

`JSON.stringify()` method converts the object to a JSON string.

Comment: I think you are missing my point. I know how to call pubsub functions programmatically. I am wondering about the functions GUI, so I guess I should have said GUI instead of just UI. I'll edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact @eespinola was pointing you almost to the right direction. If you examine carefully the [link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/pubsub#functions-calling-direct-pubsub-http-nodejs) he provided you'll find the Cloud Functions default subscriber snippet:

```js
/**
 * Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
 *
 * @param {object} pubsubMessage The Cloud Pub/Sub Message object.
 * @param {string} pubsubMessage.data The "data" property of the Cloud Pub/Sub Message.
 */
exports.subscribe = (pubsubMessage) => {
  // Print out the data from Pub/Sub, to prove that it worked
  console.log(Buffer.from(pubsubMessage.data, 'base64').toString());
};
```

This snippet is showing that the pubsub event contains a field named "data" that is a base64 encoded string. Moreover if you search the API documentation for PubSub you'll find the syntax of the [JSON representation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) for the message:

```
{
  "data": string,
  "attributes": {
    string: string,
    ...
  },
  "messageId": string,
  "publishTime": string
}
```

Therefore you need to encode your payload as base64 string with that format and convert it back to a Javascript object inside the function.

Comment: I was afraid that was going to be the answer. In that case the UI is just pretty useless as an easy to use interface. It should really provide fields for these properties and convert the JSON to base64 for use in data. Requiring the user to convert it outside the UI is just nuts. I'll submit a feature request.